# C++ Multitype object idea

Tags: c++, char, wchar-t

My program needs a lot of ANSI<=>UNICODE conversation so I got the idea to create multitype object which will convert all stuff easier than addinational function and a lot of new/delete. Pseudocode:

```
class CWchar // char based
{
public:
    public static implicit operator wchar_t*(CWchar cw)
    {
        // converting cw.data to wchar_t
        // up to U+FFFF conversion needed
    }
    public static implicit operator char*(CWchar cw)
    {
        return cw.data;
    }
    CWchar& CWchar::operator=(const char* c)
    {
        data = *c; 
        return *this;
    }
    CWchar& CWchar::operator=(const wchar_t* c)
    {
        //conversion to char* ...
        return *this;
    }

    // add some smart pointers, garbage collector, and leave delete

private:
    char* data;
}
```

Is that really worth coding or should I think about another solution? Maybe there is already done project? Or maybe I am wrong and this idea is bad? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do so much conversion? Is it possible to have just one bridge which interfaces the Unicode side with the non-Unicode side?

Comment: My application is mini IM, it receives multibyte char* and I need to convert it to wide wchar_t* so for example greek alphabet would be formatted good.

Comment: @MikeKwan I forgot to add notification, could You say something more about bridge idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [codecvt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt).  This allows you to convert between Char* and multibyte wchar_t* streams.  This is part of the standard library.  The third edition of The C++ Programming Language by Stroustrup has a nice appendix on this.